# How to Search and Rewrite a CSV file using PHP?

Tags: php, csv, search, url-rewriting

so I'm very new to coding with PHP and although it is not my first programming language, I am having a difficult time learning enough expressions along with proper syntax to understand what to do. Can someone please help me write a simple script that will do the following:

1.Read a CSV file
2.Search that CSV file for a string
3.If the string is found, rewrite a specific section of that particular row of the CSV file
(Optional) 4. If you cannot do 3, then: delete that specific row altogether from the CSV file

Other Important Notes: 
-The CSV file has 3 arguments per row 
1. one, two, three
2. four, five, six

-I would be scanning the first argument in the CSV file for the string

-I would be adjusting the second argument in the CSV file

Any and all help will be appreciated! Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I suggest looking into fgetcsv() and fputcsv(), you'll have to read each line and then modify it and write it in another file.

Comment: @derp I need to figure out how to access the information, process it and then change it or rewrite it.

Comment: @ArtisticPheonix Thank you, I will start looking into those!

Comment: @Avix - see my answer that's the most basic I could do for you, you might want some more validation if file_exists and is_file etc..  Sure no problem I have a good class for this stuff I do a lot at work with CSV but it's not exactly publishable, because of some dependancies - in short it uses SplFileObj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will get you started.

```
$input = fopen('input.csv', 'r');  //open for reading
$output = fopen('output.csv', 'w'); //open for writing


echo '<pre>'; //for debuging
while( false !== ( $data = fgetcsv($input) ) ){  //read each line as an array

    //modify data here
    var_export( $data );
    echo '<br />'; //also for debuging

     //write modified data to new file
    fputcsv( $output, $data);
}

//close both files
fclose( $input );
fclose( $output );

// delete input if you want to with unlink( 'input.csv' );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

and

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

enjoy!

If you want to get fancy ( or if you prefer OOP over procedural ) you can use this

http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php

but the kicker is if you are on PHP < 5.4 there is no fputcsv method, seems they forgot it before 5.4.

Comment: Thank you very much! This will definitely give me the start that I need! :)

Comment: I added some printable stuff, so you can read the output etc...  There was also a missing '$' in the last fclose() call.